# What is the purpose of using "plan" vs "end" in substack/tape?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, tdd, node.js-tape

substack's tape testing module allows you to specify the number of assertions ahead of time with the `plan` method, and then it will automatically call `end` for you.  Why not just put `end` at the end of a test?  What is the difference between using `plan`, and `end`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The first example on the readme](https://github.com/substack/tape#example) shows a situation where `plan` works but `end` wouldn't - asynchronous test resolution. In this case, you're not explicitly saying *when* the tests should all have resolved, you're saying how many should eventually resolve:

```js
test('timing test', function (t) {
    t.plan(2);

    t.equal(typeof Date.now, 'function');
    var start = Date.now();

    setTimeout(function () {
        t.equal(Date.now() - start, 100);
    }, 100);
});
```

If we were using `end`, the intuitive way to write this test would be as follows:

```js
test('timing test', function (t) {
    t.equal(typeof Date.now, 'function');
    var start = Date.now();

    setTimeout(function () {
        t.equal(Date.now() - start, 100);
    }, 100);

    t.end();
});
```

...but this would end the test before the second assertion has had a chance to run.

You can extrapolate this further to any kind of situation where asynchronous or dynamic code needs to execute.

Comment: Can we not put a `t.end()` into the setTimeout() callback?

Comment: You could. In hindsight this isn't a very good example — a better demonstration of plan would be something that involved potential race conditions, were a certain number of conditions are expected to resolve, but no single conditional resolution can claim to take responsibility for concluding the test. The asynchronous element is orthogonal.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense! Thanks Barney.